# What would be a more elegant approach to calling a wrapper while giving it a function to run

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, lambda

I have a wrapper function `wrapper(param1, param2, param3, myfunc)`, and myfunc which is defined as `myfunc(param1, param2, param3)`.

I want to call the wrapper on myfunc within a function call which takes a function as a parameter and calls it with parameters. Right now, my function call looks like `caller((param1, param2, param3) => wrapper(param1, param2, param3, myfunc))`.

Within wrapper, of course, there's a line `myfunc(param1, param2, param3)`.

Is there any way I could rewrite this all to make the function call more elegant? I want to be able to easily call wrapper in other places (which provide it with the first 3 parameters) and somehow give it a function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not switch the parameters and get the callback first and then the parameters.

```
const wrapper = (fn, ...args) => () => fn(...args);
```

This approach allows to have arbitrary count of paramters.

---

The *old* standard approach is to bind the function, like

```
function wrapper(fn, ...args) {
    return fn.bind(null, ...args);
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to get rid of the lambda within my caller call.

I'd love to have something like `caller(wrapper.myfunc)`/`caller(myfunc.wrapper)` (and I'd rewrite wrapper to fit).

It's worth noting that while I can rewrite both wrapper, and myfunc (but I'd rather keep myfunc the way it is), caller is a library function I can't rewrite. I'm of course using placeholder names to abstract the problem, because I want to learn the most universal solution (for ES6/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer. I changed `wrapper` from `wrapper(param1, param2, param3, myfunc)` to `funcCaller(myfunc, param1, param2, param3)`, and made another function `wrapper = (func) => funcCaller.bind(null, func)`.

I don't understand why it had to be ordered like this though. I'd love it if someone could explain why the orders are flipped like that.